# How to access contents of an s3 bucket through cloudformation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I currently have set up an S3 Bucket with a single file in it. I also have a cloudformation template that spins up an ec2 instance with an IAM role that I believe allows access to this S3 Bucket. How exactly do I access this file in my ec2 instance? I would like this file to be present on the instance right when the stack finishes deploying.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/authenticated-file-downloads-with-cloudformation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach a role to your instance. Here's an example

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Attach IAM Role to an EC2
Resources:
  Test:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType:
        Ref: InstanceType
      IamInstanceProfile:
        Ref: ListS3BucketsInstanceProfile
  ListS3BucketsInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
      Roles:
      - Ref: ListS3BucketsRole
  ListS3BucketsPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: ListS3BucketsPolicy
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
          - s3:List*
          Resource: "*"
      Roles:
      - Ref: ListS3BucketsRole
  ListS3BucketsRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
            - ec2.amazonaws.com
          Action:
          - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: "/"
```

`ListS3BucketsInstanceProfile` assumes the role : `ListS3BucketsRole` .
`ListS3BucketsPolicy` is attached to `ListS3BucketsRole` which allows the role to list all s3 objects.

With this your EC2 instance can list files on S3